# Control de Excepciones Genexus

Tags: genexus

Cordial Saludo,

Mi duda es la siguiente. Existe alguna funcionalidad dentro de Genexus que ayude a controlar las excepciones que se generen ya sea por temas de bases de datos o por temas de conectividad?, esto con el fin de controlar y enviar un mensaje mas sencillo a el usuario, ejemplo "Error en el sistema, consulte al administrador"

Gracias.

Ejemplo mensaje generado que genera inconformidad con los usuarios finales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para controlar errores relacionados con la base de datos, existe la Rule **[Error_Handler](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6853,Error_Handler%20Rule)**.

Por ejemplo, en el procedure que quieras controlar, en las rules debes agregar:

```
error_handler('DBErrors');
```

Y en el source:

```
Sub 'DBErrors'
    Msg("Código error: " + &gxDBErr)
    Msg("Descripción: " + &gxDBTxt)
    Msg("Operación: " + &gxOper)
EndSub
```

Para controlar errores de excepciones, a partir de Genexus 16 Upgrade 7, existe la rule **[Exception_Handler](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?44808,Exception_Handler%20Rule)**.

En el procedure que quieras controlar, en las rules debes agregar:

```
Exception_Handler('Controlar_Errores');
```

Y en el source:

```
Sub 'Controlar_Errores'
    Msg("Type: " + &GXExceptionType)
    Msg("Details: " + &GXExceptionDetails)
    Msg("Stack: " + &GXExceptionStack)
EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

El Exception_Handler solo te permite llamar, por ejemplo, a un proc que te guarde un log con el error, pero se detiene la aplicación.
Lamentablemente vas a tener que insertar código hava o .Net para hacer un Catch/Try y envolver todo dentro de este.